# android problem to open the allow permission window of facebook on phone

Tags: android, facebook

In my application i am trying to connect with the facebook. After login it will ask for allow permission if any permissions are there and also can post wall.

Same app is work properly on emulator but on phone login window and allow permission window is not coming.
Why it happening like this?

Below my code for login,

```
  public class LoginListener implements DialogListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            if (testAuthenticatedApi())
                System.out.println("Login successfully...");
            if (testAuthenticatedErrors()) {
                System.out.println("Login successfully...");
            }
        }
}


 public boolean testAuthenticatedApi() {
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) 
            return false;
        try {
            Log.d("Tests", "Testing request for 'me'");
            String response = facebook.request("me");
            JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);
            if (obj.getString("name") == null || 
                    obj.getString("name").equals("")) {
                return false;
            }

            Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", "hello world");
            parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
            response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                    "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
                return false;
            }

            Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API delete");
            response = response.replaceAll("\\{\"id\":\"", "");
            response = response.replaceAll("\"\\}", "");
            response = facebook.request(response, new Bundle(), 
                    "DELETE");
            if (!response.equals("true")) return false;

            Log.d("Tests", "Testing old API wall post");
            parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
            parameters.putString("attachment", 
                "{\"name\":\"Name=Title\"," +
                "\"href\":\"http://www.google.fr/\",\"" +
                "caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description" +
                "\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":" +
                "\"http://www.kratiroff.com/logo-facebook.jpg\"," +
                "\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/\"}]," +
                "\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"" +
                "Facebook homepage\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook." +
                "com\"}}}");;
            response = facebook.request(parameters);
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
                return false;
            }

            Log.d("Tests", "Testing wall post delete");
            response = response.replaceAll("\"", "");
            response = facebook.request(
                    response, new Bundle(), "DELETE");
            if (!response.equals("true")) return false;

            Log.d("Tests", "All Authenticated Tests Passed");
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean testAuthenticatedErrors() {
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) return false;

        Log.d("Tests", "Testing that request for 'me/invalid' is rejected");
        try {
            Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/invalid"));
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.d("Tests", "*" + e.getMessage() + "*");
            if (!e.getMessage().equals("Unknown path components: /invalid")) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        Log.d("Tests", "Testing that old API call with invalid method fails");
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "something_invalid");
        try {
            Util.parseJson(facebook.request(params));
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.d("Tests", "*" + e.getMessage() + "*");
            if (!e.getMessage().equals("Unknown method") ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        Log.d("Tests", "All Authenticated Error Tests Passed");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: show some code where you request authorization.

Comment: please show `facebook.authorize(...)` and authorize listener, not `facebook.request(...)`.

Comment: facebook.authorize(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginListener());

Comment: do you added ` facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in `onActivityResult` method?

Comment: yes i added that also,like this                                            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

Comment: how to pass FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH in the authorize methods in Facebook.java?

Comment: `facebook.authorize(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginListener());`

Comment: thanks. Its working. But i m not getting, Plz clearly tell me what it does. Bcz in phone i already loged in through oficial app, but when i run my app it again ask foe username & pwd for login why? it should automaticaly login through that ofical facebook username and pwd na? and go to the Permission window na?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be the SSO (Single Sign On) feature of the login.

Following link might be helpful.

[facebook login dialog disappears soon after loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245321/facebook-login-dialog-disappears-soon-after-loading)

http://ukgupta.blogspot.com/2011/07/facebook-implementation-into-android.html

Comment: `facebook.authorize(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginListener());`

Comment: thanks. Its working. But i m not getting, Plz clearly tell me what it does.

Comment: Bcz in phone i already loged in through oficial app, but when i run my app it again ask foe username & pwd for login why? it should automaticaly login through that ofical facebook username and pwd na? and go to the Permission window na?

Comment: go through the second link. 5th paragraph.

Comment: It should, but since in your question you said "phone login window and allow permission window is not coming. Why it happening like this", this is the default behaviour of SSO. if you have already signed then it the permission window will not come.

Comment: I ll not pass Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH this. its ok if login window ll not come bcz it ll take all this from official facebook app but in my code i gave some permission , so it should go to the permisson window na?  permission window also not coming thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the messages returned via the error log in ADB? 
It may be helpful to everyone else reading this, so they can then help you. :)

Comment: no errors. Its working nicly on emulator. Only problem with phone

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to force the use of legacy
               dialog-based authorization, pass FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH for this
                 parameter. Otherwise just omit this parameter and Facebook
                 will use a suitable default
It is passed in this authorize code as 3rd parameter.

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
        int activityCode, final DialogListener listener)
```

If it is less than zero(< 0) ,it will not need SSO.Hope it will help others.For further query please see
[Unable to retrieve access token for facebook on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919276/unable-to-retrieve-access-token-for-facebook-on-real-device/9010189#9010189)