# Android Facebook app: access token expiry ( expires_in ) is always 0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an app which uses facebook integration. I am trying to receive the access_token and expires_in tokens from the facebook library classes. Once i am logged in I get the access_token correctly but i always get expires_in token always 0. And because of that I isSessionValid() method always returns false. Kindly let me know if anyone has faced this issue and solved it.

My code runs perfectly fine when i do not have the Facebook app installed in the emulator. I get the webview and I can log in and update status. But when I install Facebook app, clicking on the update status menu option opens the Facebook app, I get redirected to the permissions page and then I get an error saying " Failed to receive access token". This is infact because of the expires_in token being 0.

i do not want to ask the users of the app to uninstall the Facebook app if they have installed. kindly let me the solution to this problem.

Thanks,
Punit

Comment: if you put permission `offline_access`, the the token expiry is 0

Comment: I had used 'offline_access' initially. Now i took it off, i'm still getting expires_in as 0. Does the change in the Permissions take some time to reflect?

Comment: Got it working. I had to log into facebook and revoke the `offline_access` permission to get it working. Thanks a lot @adil-soomro

Comment: I want to mark @adil-soomro 's comment as correct answer. Wish he had put his comment as an answer :-D

Comment: yea! I've posted the answer. you may mark it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you put permission `offline_access`, the token expiry is 0.

For any one else having this issue (if you had put `offline_access` permission and later removed) follow the steps:

- Go to your facebook profile setting and remove your app.
- and then do login again.
- Give permission to your app again.

Alternately you can do this:

- Go to your facebook profile setting > Apps > **Your_App** and remove "Access my data any time" permission.
- Save changes made.
- Re-run **Your_App**(i.e. with no `offline_access` permission now).

Comment: Thanks, this i was looking for :) But when i used facebook sdk with Access my data anytime it was working fine with Android 2.1 and above till android 4.0, this issue i have seen only after Android 4.0 and higher

Answer (score 0):

Have you mentioned Key Hash in the app that you created on facebook? If not, create a valid one and mention it. This usually occurs because of the new update features of facebook, However, older versions of facebook work well each time. You can check this by uninstalling updates on your facebook app, and run your code. It still works fine. Learn more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919276/unable-to-retrieve-access-token-for-facebook-on-real-device)

Comment: I have used a valid Key Hash. And Uninstalling updates is not helping.

Comment: I get the access_token correctly. I only get the expires_in as 0. I want to know how to get the correct expires_in value.